# What titles does Cthulhu have?

Tags: cthulhu-mythos

Various deities have titles associated with them - 'The chosen one', 'Messiah', 'Son of God' etc.

What titles are associated with Cthulhu?

I'm looking for titles like 'Destroyer of Worlds', 'The Dead Dreamer'.

Answers don't have to be canonical - pop culture references are fine.

Comment: Other than "Great", I don't recall any other titles applied to Cthulhu in H.P.'s work. I guess [He](http://www.hello-cthulhu.com/?date=2003-11-30) has no need of such things.

Comment: @JoeL. ^^ Haha great reference. I got 'Elder god of the damned' from there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The adjectives **Great**, **Dread**, and **Dead** are often applied to Cthulhu:

> the secret priests would take **great Cthulhu** from his tomb to revive His subjects and resume his rule of earth
>   <sub>-- Castro, a Cthulhu cultist</sub>

(I can't find a canon source for "**Dread Cthulhu**", but this phrase, with quotes, has [over 10,000 hits on Google](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22dread+cthulhu%22).)

> Ph'nglui mglw'nafh Cthulhu R'lyeh wgah'nagl fhtagn (In his house at R'lyeh, **dead Cthulhu** waits dreaming.
>   <sub>-- Frequent chant of Cthulhu cultists</sub>

His actual *titles* listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cthulhu) are:

- **High Priest of the Great Old Ones**
- **The Great Dreamer**
- **The Sleeper of R'lyeh**